# Cannot launch library from interface builder

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, xcode4

I have xcode 4 and I see no way of launching library from IB.  So I cannot add image buttons to my app.  apple-shift-L didnt work and I dont see a tools menu option.

Anyway around this?

Can I programmatically add buttons?

Comment: You can do **everything** programmatically. But you should probably try to figure out what's wrong with your IB setup.

Answer (score 0):

The library in Xcode 4 is tricky to find and occasionally hidden.

In IB mode, make sure the right drawer is open, then look at the very bottom of it. There should be a small area containing the Library. If not, there should be 4 buttons at the very bottom of the right drawer. In order: "Piece of Paper", "Brackets", "Box", "Movie". Click the box to open the Library. Then drag to resize it to a humane height.

Answer (score 0):

They moved it to View->Utilities->Object Library